# How to create multiple JSON array to JSON object in servlets

Tags: java, json, jsp, servlets, serialization

I need to create variable amount of JSON objects and  based on the result set from a database query. States retrieving from mysql database. I am saving the response in JSON array but it is saving in multiple JSON objects like that:

```
    jString userid = rs2.getString("state");
    JSONObject mainObj = new JSONObject();
    JSONArray jsArray = new JSONArray();
    jsArray.put(userid );
    mainObj.put("states", jsArray);
```

With this output:

```
    {"states":["karnataka"]}
    {"states":["kerala"]}
    {"states":["chennai"]}
```

Can I get output in single JSON object like `{"States":"karnataka","kerala","chennai"}`?

Comment: it really depends on your JSON structure. you can structure it as a list:
`"States": [ "karnataka", "kerala", "chennai" ]`

Comment: BTW, your proposed JSON structure is invalid.

Answer (score 1):

You probably just got some code structure confused.

Try something like this:

```
JSONArray jsArray = new JSONArray();
JSONObject mainObj = new JSONObject();

//some kind of loop 
{
    jString userid = rs2.getString("state");
    jsArray.put(userid);
}
mainObj.put("states", jsArray);
```